# Hiberante Inner join gives an 'Path expected for join' exception

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, inner-join

I have the below entities,

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "person")
    public class Person implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        // Other fields 
    }

     @Entity
        @Table(name = "agreement")
        public class Agreement implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 15L;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "id")
            private Long id;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
            private Person person;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
            private Company company;

        }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "company")
    public class Company implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
        private String name;
    }
```

I need to get all the persons who has a agreement with the company with the company ID 45. Below is the native query that I have written to fetch the details.

```
SELECT distinct p.* ROM person p INNER JOIN agreement a ON a.person_id = p.id where a.company_id = 45;
```

But I was told to convert it to a JPA entity query. And I came up with the below,

```
SELECT distinct p  FROM Person p INNER JOIN Agreement a WHERE a.person = p AND a.company.id = 45;
```

But this gives me the below exception,

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path
>   expected for join! [SELECT distinct p  FROM Person p INNER JOIN
>   Agreement a WHERE a.person = p AND a.company.id = 45]     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:268)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:305

Can someone help me out what I have done wrong in the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA uses paths in the HQL statement, to relate from one entity to the other and since it didn't find any it is complaining. You can try below query.

```
SELECT distinct p FROM Agreement a JOIN a.person p WHERE a.company.id = 45;
```